# pyodbc failed to connect to MSSQL

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

I want to connect to mssql server using pyodbc but somehow I can't connect.

here is the code

```
import pyodbc 
server = '172.xx.xx.xx,1433' 
database = 'DATABASE_BI' 
username = 'COMPANY\test.xx' 
password = 'test123!@#' 
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';UID='+username+';PWD='+ password)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

and here is the output

```
OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]TCP Provider: The
wait operation timed out.\r\n (258) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL
Server]Login timeout expired (0); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A network
related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.
Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is
configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. (258)')
```

I don't know what makes it error. Is it because of the mssql server reject the request?

Comment: `username = 'COMPANY\test.xx'` ... this is a Windows login or Active Directory account, right? You can't use Windows login credentials with UID and PWD (which is "SQL Login authentication") so remove them from the connection string and append `trusted_connection=yes` instead.

Comment: thanks. you solved my problem